# Qt: How to transfer base class to object created in that class

Tags: c++, qt

I've created base class - MainWindow. In this class I create object of another class "SecondWindow". By using object of SecondWindow I want to use function() method that is defined in base class. How can I do this?

I've tried to transfer my base class as a parameter to SecondWindow object but that wasn't working (probably becouse in MainWindow I have included "secondWindow.h" and in SecondWindow I tried to include "mainwindow.h" header files). Is there way to simply use functions/variables of base class?

mainwindow.h

```
#include<QMainWindow>
#include "secondwindow.h"
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();
    SecondWindow *secondWindow;
    void function();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    secondWindow = new secondWindow();
    function();
}
void MainWindow::function()
{
    qDebug()<<"yes";
}
```

secondwindow.h

```
class SecondWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SecondWindow();

}
```

secondwindow.cpp

```
#include "secondwindow.h"

SecondWindow::SecondWindow()
{
//here I want to use function();
}
```

Comment: inherit the `MainWindow` instead of `QMainWindow`, i.e. `class TrackWindow : public MainWindow` then you can call the `function()` function

Comment: Problem with inheriting - that what I got after inherit MainWindow instead of QMainWindow: "expected class-name before '{' token" ("{" just under 'class TrackWindow : public MainWindow')

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I believe `TrackWindow` in your code snippet should have been `SecondWindow`. I edited it. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, your design looks suspect to me. Can you explain why `MainWindow` needs a pointer to a `SecondWindow` in the first place?

Comment: Here is a bit more code - directly from my project: http://textuploader.com/dq91u  . I I didn't give all my code here on stack, becouse don't want to make littering.

Comment: You don't need to post full code. You only need to explain in English what it is you're trying to do. Why does `MainWindow` need a pointer to a `SecondWindow`? Because right now, it's very confusing. There are virtually zero cases where a base class needs a pointer to a derived class, yet you seem to want to make `SecondWindow` derive from `MainWindow`.

Comment: I'm adding it to layout, so I use pointer for it

Comment: Does `function()` need to be in `MainWindow`? Does it access private or protected members?

Comment: Probably I could place it in second window, but I was curious about this problem. Thank you for replies. At the moment I think that I have to work hard on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to inherit your MainWindow class, which would then inherit QMainWindow()

So in secondwindow.h you would change

```
class SecondWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SecondWindow();

};
```

to

```
#include "mainwindow.h"    
class SecondWindow : public MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SecondWindow();

};
```

And you will then be able to use function() in secondwindow.cpp

Also, you have another issue at hand and it's that your mainwindow uses a pointer to second window, but you will then have a circular dependence issue. (You need SecondWindow in order to compile MainWindow, however, you want SecondWindow to be able to use `function()`).

To resolve this, you need to forward-declare SecondWindow in your MainWindow class.

In mainwindow.h remove `#include "secondwindow.h"` and replace it with `class SecondWindow;`